# Ubuntu Studio 8+ Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio

I upgraded my laptop from *Ubuntu Studio 17+* to 18, but it crashed...
Then I tried to run the recovery mode down to all the previous versions, but of no luck. It froze...

Then I tried reinstalling the downgrade version from my USB. Unfortunately, when I opened the Firefox browser, it froze again...
I waited for a long time, but it's still in stuck frame. Then I reinstalled it again - thinking it might be because of some errors - but again, it's stuck.

I liked *Ubuntu Studio* and I'd like to use it again.
I'm using a *DELL Latitude E6230*.